# Does the java compiler internally create constructors for interfaces?

Tags: java

Below is a simple program that I have:

```
interface X {}

public class Y implements X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new Y();
    }
}
```

Now, as far as I know, the variable *x* would be able to hold an object type of *Y* if an *is-a* relationship existed between *Y* and *X*. That is to say that class *Y* is a type of interface *X*.

But we know that interfaces cannot be instantiated and cannot have constructors. Does the compiler then create a constructor for the interface in the .class file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But we know that interfaces cannot be instantiated and cannot have constructors. Does the compiler then create a constructor for the interface in the .class file ?

No.

You are not instantiating X here, you are instantiating object Y and you are assigning it to X, because Y is of type X.

The paradigm is called as [programming to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

Comment: Thanks. So, does Y implementing X imply that Y is a type of X? If yes, that would mean that, interfaces are just a different form of abstract classes.

Comment: @Moses True. Your understanding is correct.